# Отправка с android на сервер запроса firebase

Tags: java, android, python, django, firebase

Появилась идея создания сервиса отслеживания пользователя.
Идея состоит в том что пользователь заходит на сервер нажимает кнопку получить данные, срабатывает ajax который отправляет на скрипт питона (django), скрипт отправляет в систему notific google  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send с идентификатором устройства. Устройство принимает  сообщение и выполняет команду на получения местоположения. Возникает вопрос, что делать дальше. Нужно как то отправить обратно на сервер где пользователь нажал кнопку получить местоположение, данные с устройства. Как это можно реализовать?
Сервер python+django (ajax), клиент android?

Comment: Что в Вашем понимании означает "Пользователь заходит на сервер" ?

Comment: веб интерфейс, там находится кнопка и тэг в котором будет определятся положение.